# How to add notifications to icon in iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios

I see that some applications in iPhone show a red circle with the number of notifications from the application, how is that done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:99]`

Zero value hides the badge.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a Badge, and it is used for `icons`, `tabbaritems` mostly.

You can set it up like

```
UITabBarItem *featured = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFeatured tag:0]; 
featured.badgeValue = @"1";
```

Comment: The question specifically referred to the badge on the Springboard, which was correctly answered by Jose.