# How to show the notification count in app icon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, badge

i like to show the push notification count like this ,i have searched about it but can't get the right solution.

[image]

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797037/how-to-add-notifications-to-icon-in-ios-application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating iOS badge without push notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861131/updating-ios-badge-without-push-notifications)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set it everywhere. E.g:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:123]; // this one
}
```

Comment: anhtu bro one help ?

Comment: i like to do auto update of notification count ,so i tried [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber]; but didn't get .

Comment: i gave this line of code inside pushnotification did receive method

Comment: Are you sure it call the line? And more you should +1  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber+1];`

Comment: yes this line called and when i click the notification its again shown 1.

Answer (score 5):

When you receive your notification this method is got called:

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

This will contain a NSDictionary

```
`(NSDictionary *)userInfo`
```

update the app icon badge count using the function

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];
```

Your Payload look like this:

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : "You got your emails.",
    "badge" : 9
        }
}
```

> To hide the badge use Zero(0)

Answer (score 1):

Its called badge, you can write following line to achieve this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:22];
```

Please refer to following link if you want to understand its working in sample application:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-add-a-badge-to-the-application-icon/

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4 you can set badge by adding this line:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = <Int_count>
```