# How to set an app icon badge number in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, notifications, badge

**Problem:**

I am trying to set an app icon badge number in iOS 10, however it is failing. I understand `UIUserNotificationSettings` is now deprecated in iOS and `UNNotificationSettings` replaces it.

**Question:**

> How do I modify the below code to use `UNNotificationSettings` to
>   update the icon badge number in iOS 10? Or is there another concise method?

**Code:**

The following code shows how I set badges from iOS 7 - iOS 9.

```
let badgeCount: Int = 123
let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

if #available(iOS 7.0, *) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
}

if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge], categories: nil))
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
}

if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge], categories: nil))
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
}

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // ?????
}
```

Comment: I'm using the same as your code for iOS9 and it's working on my iOS10 devices physically and in simulator.

Comment: but i guess you're looking for an answer in swift 3?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, a Swift 3 answer would be helpful. But that's interesting that it is working on iOS 10 considering it is deprecated? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiusernotificationsettings I'm a bit puzzled now.

Comment: like said. i'm using the exact same version as in ios9 and it's working without any problems. displaying the badge in simulator and physical iphone 6 and 7

Comment: got it. posting it in a second

Comment: bro. could you then accept my answer please...

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797037/how-to-add-notifications-to-icon-in-ios-application

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement `UserNotifications` into `AppDelegate`.

```
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

And then use the following code within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //
        }
    }
    return true

}
```

[Here](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/08/22/23-notifications-in-ios-10/) you can find tons of important stuff on the **notifications** topic.

For the badge:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.badge = 10 // your badge count
```

Comment: Thank you @David Seek . I'll give this a go.

Comment: Thanks @David Seek , haven't yet got around to testing this. I do have another app icon badge type of question with a bounty that you might be able to help solve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922580/voiceover-accessibility-label-and-hint-for-an-app-icon-badge-number