# How to add VoiceOver accessibility to an App's Icon Badge Number?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, accessibility, uiaccessibility

> **Question:**
>
> How do I add a custom VoiceOver accessibility `Label` or `Hint` to an App
>   Icon Badge Number?

[image]           [image]           [image]

---

**For example**, when the iOS Setting `Accessibility > VoiceOver` is turned `On`, VoiceOver reads aloud items touched on screen. For the App Store and Mail icons, the following is read out aloud:

> App Store icon, VoiceOver says: *"App Store. **2 updates available**.
>   Double tap to open."*
>
> Mail icon, VoiceOver says: *"Mail. **1 unread message**. Double tap
>   to open."*

***But***, for the project I am working on, the VoiceOver read out is generic and not entirely helpful:

> My App icon, VoiceOver says: *"My App. **123 new items**. Double tap to
>   open."*

The phrase ***"... new items"*** is too vague, not accurate, and I'm certain there must be a way to change this with a custom string to make it read better through setting an `accessibilityLabel`, `accessibilityHint` or something similar.

But how exactly in Swift code?

Many thanks.

---

**Additional observation:**

Using the Simulator Accessibility Inspector, it appears the VoiceOver values come from `Label` - "My App" and `Value` - "123 new items". So updated in the code I have tried setting the `accessibilityValue` to something custom - "123 custom description.". But still no luck, VoiceOver continues to read *"My App. 123 **new items**. Double tap to open."*

**Why isn't VoiceOver reading the custom badge value as expected?**

[image]

---

**Code:**

The below method adds a red circle App Icon Badge Number to My App's icon:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let badgeCount: Int = 123
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) { 
            //// iOS 8, iOS 9, iOS 10
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge], categories: nil))
        } else {
            //// iOS 7
        }
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
        application.accessibilityValue = "123 custom description."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears this is an "Apple-only" feature as of now... [source](http://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2015/Jan/msg00003.html)

Digging through API documentation, there doesn't seem to be any identifier that can set this for you, and I therefore think it's not publicly supported yet. It's likely been reported already, but reporting this as a request to [Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) can never hurt.

Sorry this is probably not the answer you were hoping for! :/

Comment: Thank you, @BHendricks . Yes, I came across that mail list recently too. The conversation is rather old though, a few months shy of being a two year old conversation. Maybe, and possibly overly optimistically, I’m convinced there may still be a solution as of today. It just seems too big an oversight in my opinion. In the spirit of making apps accessible for everyone, I'll keep searching. Good idea, I will file a technical support request with Apple and bug report.

Comment: Update: I contacted Apple and they got back to me and as you mentioned, they confirmed that they don't currently have API exposed to do what I'm wanting to achieve in the question. This is one for the bug reports!